# Given 1 solution to a differential equation, find another solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I find a linearly independent solution to a differential equation given a solution to the differential equation.  For example, I have this question:

> One solution of Hermite's differential equation
>   $$
> y''-2xy'=0
> $$
>   is $y_1(x)=1$. Find another linearly independent solution of the same equation.

You don't have to solve this particular question, it is just an example.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure the tag "orthogonal-polynomials" is relevant for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is reduction of order. I describe it in the case of differential equation of order 2.

**Reduction of order**

Assume that you have the differential equation
$$
y''+py'+qy=0,
$$
and that you have one solution $y_1$. Then, try to find a solution $y$ in the form
$$
y=y_1\int u\,dx,\tag{*}
$$
where $u$ is a function to be determined. Differentiating, you will find
$$
y_1''\int u\,dx+2y_1u+y_1u'+p\bigl[y_1'\int u\,dx+y_1u\bigr]+qy_1\int u\,dx=0,
$$
which reduces to
$$
y_1u'+(2y_1'+py_1)u=0.\tag{**}
$$
This is a linear differential equation of order one, which in principle can be solved using the method with integrating factor.

**Your example**

For your example, this is not the easiest method, but you have that $y_1=1$ solves
$$
y''-2xy'=0.
$$
Here, $p=-2x$, $q=0$, and so the new differential equation $(**)$ becomes
$$
u'-2xu=0.
$$
An integrating factor is $e^{-x^2}$, so
$$
(ue^{-x^2})'=0.
$$
Integration gives
$$
u=Ce^{x^2}.
$$
Inserting this into $(*)$ gives your second solution
$$
y=C\int e^{x^2}\,dx.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Given a solution $y_1(x) = 1$, the Wronskian becomes very simple:

$$W(y_1, y_2)(x) = \begin{vmatrix}y_1(x) & y_2(x) \\ y_1'(x) & y_2'(x)\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}1 & y_2(x) \\ 0 & y_2'(x)\end{vmatrix} = y_2'(x) \neq 0$$

To relate it to a function in $x$, we use

> [**Abel's identity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity): Given $y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = 0$. The Wronskian satisfies $$W(y_1, y_2)(x) = W(y_1, y_2)(x_0) e^{-\int_{x_0}^x p(\eta) d\eta}$$

Given that  $p(x) = -2x$ in the DE, $$e^{-\int_{x_0}^x p(\eta) d\eta} = e^{x^2}e^{-x_0^2}$$

Set $c_2 = y_2'(x_0) e^{-x_0^2}$.

$$y_2'(x) = c_2 e^{x^2}$$

and we obtain $y_2(x)$ by integration (using error function erfi(x)).

Answer (score 0):

The equation $$y'' - xy' = 0 ⇔ y''e^{-x^2/2} - xy'e^{-x^2/2} = 0$$ 
where $e^{-x^2/2}$ is the 'integrating factor' can be written as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[y'e^{-x^2/2}\right] = 0$$
so that for any solution $y$, we have
$$ y'e^{-x^2/2} = C$$
so $$y(x) = C_1∫_{-∞}^xe^{-t^2/2}dt +C_2$$
describes all possible solutions. Choosing $C_1≠ 0$ gives you one that is linearly independent from $1$.

Comment: the D.E in question is $y''-2xy'=0$ not $y''-xy'=0$

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a solution, lets say, $y_1$, search for a second solution of the form: $y_2 = v(x)y_1(x)$ solve this equation for $v$.

Comment: In OP's example $y_1=1$. So this method will not be too fruitful...

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{y''}{y'}=2x$$
$$\log|y'|=x^2+C$$
$$y'= e^{x^2+C}$$
or
$$y'= Ke^{x^2}$$
$$y=\int  Ke^{x^2}dx$$
$$y= \frac{K\sqrt{\pi}}{2}erfi(x)+C_1$$
depending on the condition of equation ,we can find the $K,C_1$